# I need to pour a concrete porch above the outside wall stucco screed level. What kind of barrier(s) do I need?

Tags: concrete

Pouring concrete porch against stucco wall above screed level. What kind of barrier(s) do I need?

Comment: Not nearly enough info to know how to give an informed answer. Barrier's ?  screed level ?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.